# JQuery get attribute value with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I want to  get the **href** attr value based on the value of the **rel** attr . How do I do this in javascript?

```
<links>
    <link href="https://someurl/index/16380" rel="self"/>
    <link href="https://someurl/index/16380/streams?lang=en" rel="streams"/>
    <link href="https://someurl/index/16380/bif" rel="bif" />
</links>
```

something along the line ....

```
$(xml).find('link').each(function(){
 if(rel == 'streams'){
   this.streamurl = $(this).attr('href');
 }
});
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('rel');`, unless I'm missing something here?

Comment: So you want to know how to read the rel attribute? If so @ShadowWizard has your answer

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I want to get the value of href where  rel="streams".  $(this).attr('rel'); would just give me the value of rel.

Comment: Javascript ?? looks like you are using jQuery..\

Comment: @Fabii right, so you need to compare `$(this).attr('rel')` with the value you want it to have. It's just really basic and you appear to be a decent programmer that's why I'm confused here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard simple oversight on my part. Merci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(xml).find('link').each(function(){

  //prevents your re-wrapping this multiple times
  var $this = $(this);

  //read the attribute
  if($this.attr('rel') == 'streams'){
     this.streamurl = $this.attr('href');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(xml).find("link[rel=streams]")
      .each(function(i,lnk) {
          lnk.streamurl = lnk.href; 
      })
```

Or

```
$(xml).find("link[rel=streams]")
      .prop("streamurl", function() {
          return this.href; 
      })
```

---

Your original code was almost correct. Just needed this:

```
if(this.rel == 'streams'){
```

instead of this:

```
if(rel == 'streams'){
```

Open your developer console, and you'd probably see something like:

> `ReferenceError: rel is not defined`